# Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on a project to recognize sign language .i tried to execute a github project for this
while i am running the code in visual code , I am getting the error as

```
 W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
```

I even followed many of the github answers for these kind of questions.

my train.py code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense , Dropout
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
sz = 128
# Step 1 - Building the CNN

# Initializing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# First convolution layer and pooling
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(sz, sz, 1), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Second convolution layer and pooling
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


# Flattening the layers
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Adding a fully connected layer
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(Dense(units=96, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.40))
classifier.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=27, activation='softmax')) # softmax for more than 2

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) # categorical_crossentropy for more than 2

# Step 2 - Preparing the train/test data and training the model
classifier.summary()

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data2/train',
                                                 target_size=(sz, sz),
                                                 batch_size=10,
                                                 color_mode='grayscale',
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data2/test',
                                            target_size=(sz , sz),
                                            batch_size=10,
                                            color_mode='grayscale',
                                            class_mode='categorical') 
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=12841, # No of images in training set
        epochs=5,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=4268) # No of images in test set

# Saving the model
model_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("model-bw.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
print('Model Saved')
classifier.save_weights('model-bw.h5')
print('Weights saved')
```

how do i resolve this issue?
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can anyone answer my question

Comment: I don't see any training in your code. I have the same issue, I'm planning to play around with my callbacks. maybe there is some stuff in there, that tensorflow doesn't like, like writing to global variables in them or something. I am guessing the error happens right at the end of the first epoch? That's how it is with my code.